# (idea) New community guideline for Migrations

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration, idea

Essentially, to better educate and guide users and mods (current and future), a community wiki post should be created, and any question that is successfully migrated out should be added to it. Should be sorted by Site that it was migrated to. As a bonus, a little blurb or reasoning on why it was migrated would be useful.

This is because the search feature for migrated questions (migrated:yes) is limited to the last few weeks only, before they get purged.

This will create a list of questions that can be viewed and reviewed as a guideline on if a specific question should also be migrated. This is in addition to communication between the mods of this SE and the Target SE.

Sure it adds a little work to the mods, but otherwise it would provide great insight on to why/when a question should be migrated.

Comment: Like this page? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/migrated/stats

Comment: @W5VO either it has a typo, or that's mod only, not globally viewable.

Comment: Well, then I guess all I can say is that this page exists for moderators.

Comment: @W5VO  I don't see it either.  Can you post a screenshot of that page?

Comment: @W5VO actually, Kortuk posted screenshots of that page a year back. From what I can tell, it only does 90 days (maybe), shows where posts migrate from/to, and percentage rejected. http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/2842/17178 It does not list the questions, nor does it show why (what the flags for those questions say). And it's for actual mods only, so it's not useful to the community as a guideline or help tool.

Answer (score 4):

There is a mod only page that shows statistics for migrations. When we post statistics on migrations this is how we collect them.

This is coming at it from the wrong angle. If you want to know conditions for migrating a question you should look at the questions on the **target site**. They decide what fits, we only migrate questions of good quality that fit their criteria.